# How to map application to docker volume

Tags: java, docker, java-ee-8

I'm new to docker and I have been trying to run a container that deploys my Java web app on a tomcat image. The problem is my app has to read and write into a file that it accesses on my machine and clearly when the app's .war file is deployed on tomcat as a docker container it cannot find the file since the file is no longer recognized. I was trying to see how I can fix that and came across docker volumes. I have the idea of storing my file in a volume and then having my application retrieve data from it but I cannot find a way to do it. I've been looking for a way to see how I can modify the path in my app to point to a file that's in a docker volume but I cannot find anything. Perhaps I missed something as I've been trying to learn more about docker volumes? Please point out the right way to do this or maybe provide a helpful link that shows how something similar can be done, or if I am completely wrong about this approach please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the official documentation on volumes and mounts
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

This is an example on how you would mount a mysql container to your drive, this is a good idea to keep the data even when the container is deleted.
Look at the point "Where to store data"

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

This is a very short version for a docker compose to mount a folder inside the container to an external folder

```
volumes:
  - /var/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

*This are only 2 lines from a complete docker-compose file but should demonstrate how to mount a data.

The folder left of the ':' Is the folder where your data is located on your drive
the folder left of the ':' to which folder inside the container this refers.

When you are looking for a file in folder './datafolder'
you should mount your the folder ./ inside your container to the folder on your drive which contains 'datafolder'

Comment: So, let's say that my app has to access a file  test.txt, and that I successfully manage to copy that file into a data volume that is mounted in this way : -v /var/dir:/var/lib/dir , would I then only have to modify the path in my app to point to /var/lib/dir/test.txt?

Comment: When your file test.txt is located at /var/dir on your volume your app needs to point to /var/lib/dir/test.txt.
Your app searches for any files located in /var/lib/dir at your volume /var/dir outside of your container  if you do: -v  /var/dir:/var/lib/dir

Comment: I see, and would there be any way to make sure that the file test.txt is always available in host directory /var/dir ? As in, could I include a command in my dockerfile that would copy the file into my app image so that whenever there is a pull of that image on any given host, the file test.txt would be  put into a directory named /var/dir so that the app can use it?

Comment: You can put test.txt into your application, but then you won't need to mount a volume inside your container to an outside volume. You could look into shadowjar, which creates a single jar from your application with everything it needs.

Comment: The thing is, this file is used a bit like a database, so I need to be able to modify the file mounted into the same volume from different containers in a way that all containers would have access to the modified file, for instance let's say container a adds data to test.txt which is on volume vol, then container b which has access to vol would be able to sed the data added to the file, same thing if data is deleted, all containers must be able to be aware of that modification

Comment: P.S: I must use this file, I cannot use a database or anything else, unfortunately

Comment: You can have other containers access the mounted volume, as this volume is on your drive and any other container could be mounted to the same volume, but keeping the file up to date for anyone pulling your container is not what this is used for. You could for example others get an update of your file when they want, but this is not possible with a pull of one of many containers

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you very much!